# Why my Powershell script doesnt work?

Tags: email, powershell, smtp, vpn

I have created script for checking if VPN connection is disconnected and try to reconnect. Its also sending emails, when 
1) cant ping VPN server with remote LAN address
2) VPN connection fails
3) VPN connection is established.

First email is sent and received properly, but Powershell gives error, when it have to send another email.

Code inside `vpn.ps1` file:

```psh
$ip = "*.*.*.*"
$result = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '$ip'"

if($result.StatusCode -eq 0) {

} else {
    Start-Sleep -s 15

    $EmailFrom = "*@*.*"
    $EmailTo = "*@*.*" 
    $Subject = "###" 
    $Body = "#####################################################"

    $SMTPServer = "*.*.*.*" 
    $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, ***)
    #$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("*@*.*", "*************");
    $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)

    rasdial.exe ********** /DISCONNECT    
    rasdial.exe ******** ****** ******

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15

    $ip = "*.*.*.*"
    $result = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '$ip'"

    if ($result.StatusCode -eq 0) {
        $EmailFrom = "*@*.*"
        $EmailTo = "*@*.*" 
        $Subject = "########" 
        $Body = "####################################" 
        $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
    } else {
        Start-Sleep -s 15

        $EmailFrom = "*@*.*"
        $EmailTo = "*@*.*" 
        $Subject = "################" 
        $Body = "##########################################" 
        $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
    }
}
```

Log when running:

```psh
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::***********> *******\vpn.ps1
#FIRST EMAIL SENT
No connections
Command completed successfully.
Connecting to *********...
Verifying username and password...
Registering your computer on the network...
Successfully connected to ******.
Command completed successfully.
Exception calling "Send" with "4" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At \\tsclient\C\New folder\vpn.ps1:26 char:9
+         $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException


PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::******
```

I have sensored usernames, passwords, addresses etc. What is wrong with my script?

Comment: "Failing sending mail." is a general error message, usually indicates failure in finding or connecting to the `$SmtpServer`

Comment: But the first email is sent properly.

Comment: Have you tried to pause for a few minutes (start with 1, then 5) before sending another mail ? Maybe there is a protection against spam on the SMTP server ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$SMTPClient` object isnt declared in the else block.
You need an instance of that object inside of the block, where you use it, or declare it outside, to have one global `$SMTPClient` object, which is present in the blocks. You also have to fill the `$SMTPClient.Credentials`.

Best solution will be, to declare both before the if Statement in line 3.

*Update*

Move these lines

```
$SMTPServer = "*.*.*.*" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, ***) 
#$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("*@*.*", "*************");
```

out of those if .. else ..

Just move it to line 2, right before the if block.

Comment: Move lines 11 to 14 above line 3.

Comment: It is declared, but doesn't look like it due to the nested `If/Else` statement, and lack of indenting on that nested `If/Else`. Script is a little hard to follow due to how the indenting is, try to ignore it and re-read the script.

Comment: TheMadTechnician is totally right, we both got owned by indenting. Re-wrote the code in the question for better readability and understanding. This answer now needs an update ... or is wrong.